# Need an array formula to show duplicates in a column

Tags: google-sheets, duplicates, array-formulas

I have a two columns (A:B) of numbers which are beeing concatenated in to one unique number in third column (C).

I need an ARRAY formula which can print some sort of text, or true/falce in to column D - next to each duplicate value of column C (ignoring blank cells of that column).

I curently have an if/countif formula (added to column E for reference) which somewhat does the work, but it has to be applied to each and every cell of the column, which is very inconveninet in this case, as sheet becomes very long (7K+ rows) and additional rows are added to the sheet by the users.

I have tried this array formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIF(C2:C,UNIQUE(C2:C))>1 )
```

but it doesn't work properly...

Link to the document:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Udtv7gdI_IMoARZfeInzSPx6C1fbmOD3xHMBBEPXQQk/edit#gid=1518627098

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In D2 I entered

```
=arrayformula(if(len(B2:B), if(countif(C2:C, C2:C)>1, "MARKER",),))
```

See if that works for you?

Comment: Perfect, just what i needed! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use the  UNIQUE function ?